# Had cat5e cable and got 1000mbps, upgraded segment of it to cat6, now limited to 100mbps

Tags: networking, switch, gigabit-ethernet, cat5e, cat6

I have a setup in my home that goes something like this:

[cable modem] -> [Netgear Gigabit switch UPSTAIRS] -> [Netgear Gigabit Switch DOWNSTAIRS] -> [Netgear Gigabit Switch OFFICE] -> [My PC]

Now, I previously had cat5e throughout the place, and routinely got close to 1000mbps over the network and coming in (I have a gigabit connection).

However, today - I replaced the trunk of line between the UPSTAIRS switch and DOWNSTAIRS switch with Cat6 cable.

My internet still works, with a few oddities:

# The link indicator on the switches (Upstairs and Downstairs) both read that they have a 100mbps connection, not 1000mbps like they did before
  # Obviously, speedtests on my PC indicate that I am limited to ~95mbps, not the 800+ I was getting before
  # My network indicator in my systray on windows has the yellow exclamation mark. When I click on the adapter properties, it says no internet, despite the fact I am on the internet right now writing this.

I have no idea what is going on, or why this is even happening. Can anyone help me shed some light? I want to reiterate that only one section of cabling has been replaced with Cat6, the rest is still cat5e.

Thanks!

Comment: I would redo the new trunk end RJ45 connectors. A bad connector on a short cable can cause severe crosstalk.

Answer (score 2):

Are your new cables terminated properly?  You may have a bad crimp (if you just terminated to an RJ-45) or a bad punch down into your jack.